# Choropleth map turns one color when filtered, sql error

Tags: sql, carto, choropleth

My data is generating a choropleth map perfectly but when I try to filter (both in the filter tab and by writing my own SQL) it turns all one color and tells me I have an SQL error.
This happens even when the SQL is generated by CardoDB's filter widget.
I have a big file - about 56,000 rows. Is this a file size issue or something else?

Comment: could you please send details about the SQL error and your username/table to us ? support@cartodb.com. it's probably a bug on our side

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sql.execute('select * from {table}', { table: 'whatever' }, { type: 'POST' }, function(...) {

}
```

in any case this should be done automatically by that method, I will file a ticket.

As a tip, if you can rewrite the SQL in order to fit in a GET request it's better for performance since CartoDB can cache the query